# Cascade Poco Exception

Tags: c++, exception, poco-libraries

I try to cascade exception in Poco.

```
void debug() {
try {
    ...
    xmlFile.parseDocument(*_sim);
    ...
    }
} catch (Poco::Exception& error) {
    std::cout << "I'm here" << endl;
    std::cout << "Error : " << error.displayText() << std::endl;
}
}

void XMLParser::parseDocument(Manager &manager) {
...
try {
    Poco::XML::NodeList* policyList = root->childNodes();
    for (uint node=0; node < policyList->length(); node++)
        if (policyList->item(node)->hasChildNodes())
            manager.insertRule(parseRule(node, policyList->item(node)));
} catch(Poco::Exception& error) {
    std::cout << "Error : " << error.displayText() << std::endl;
    error.rethrow();
}
}

Rule* XMLParser::parseRule(int flowID, Poco::XML::Node* rule) throw() {
    ....
    if (tLink._srcPort < 0)
        throw new Poco::Exception("Source Port isn't valid");
    ....
}
```

The deepest exception are thrown, but it does not continue to outer functions.
The program is terminated. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You throw a Poco::Exception pointer so you can not catch it by reference.
Remove 'new'. This should work:

```
....
if (tLink._srcPort < 0)
    throw Poco::Exception("Source Port isn't valid");
....
```